# How to generate vector pdf from react code?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-to-pdf

I want to generate vectored pdf from the react code, i tried react-to-print and react-pdf but both of them generate non vectored pdf. so is there any way by which i can generate vectored pdf from react ?

Comment: can you please tell me why it is invalid question? is the pdf generated by react-pdf vectored?

Comment: is there any suggestion for providing the functionality of editing the pdf in react code ?